# TTL Value - TimeToLive

Tags: networking, terminology, ttl

http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/time-to-live

From this article, im Confused about the defanition about this subject.
is there any chance someone help me undestand better whats going on?

### stav.

### ----------------------------------

---

EDIT:

i tried to send massage to my self from the same computer. 
when i set the TTL value to 0, the pack i send still get to me. why is that?
here is the code:

btw,this line in the Send Method.

```
server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 0);


    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    class MAIN
    {
        public static MulticastOption MulticastOption;
        private static MulticastOption CreateGroup()
        {
            MulticastOption = new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1"));
            return MulticastOption;
        }
        private static void Receive()
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
            EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
            sock.Bind(iep);
            sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, MulticastOption);
            //
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send)).Start();
            int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
            String stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("received: {0} from: {1}", stringData, ep.ToString());
            sock.Close();
        }


   private static void Send()
    {
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9051);
        IPEndPoint iep2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1"), 9050);
        server.Bind(iep);
       server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1")));
     server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 0);
        server.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test message"), iep2);
        server.Close();
    }
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        CreateGroup();
        Receive();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of this article, is confusing you?

Comment: paragraph 2 tells the defenition of the subject. i didnt get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client machines *set* the TTL value when a packet is generated, to indicate the maximum number of hops the packet is permitted to go through.

Each time a packet passes through a router the router will *decrement* the TTL value.

If the TTL value reaches zero, the router will drop the packet and return an ICMP "hop count exceeded" error message.

The main benefit of the TTL field is to stop packets bouncing around forever in the event of a *routing loop*, i.e. a network fault that causes packets to bounce around and around between the same set of routers.

Comment: i didnt understand what hops means

Comment: they're each of the lines that you see if you run a "traceroute" to someone else's IP address.  The Internet is a network of networks, with routers joining them together.  Each time a packet leaves one network and enters another, _that's_ a hop.

Comment: here is my code of my program. TTL set to zero and i still get my massage when i send it. why is that?

Comment: right, so you're using multicast TTL - like the page says, that means it's restricted to sending to the _same host_.

Comment: @Stav why wouldn't it work?  You haven't actually said why you think it shouldn't.

Comment: the TTL value = 0. so when i send the massage to the router, the router see 0 in the TTL value and delete the pack. so why i still get the massage? (i send from my computer to my computer by multicast)

Comment: if you send to a multicast group to which you're subscribed yourself the packet you see never left your computer - it would go via the internal 'loopback' virtual interface

Comment: 'loopback' virtual interface -> what is that? u mean that if i have this code but now i will try to send my sister computer insted my computer, it wont work becouse the TTL = 0? becouse for sending something to other computer, the massage must go trougth the router?